# Como fazer uma consulta dentro de um arquivo XML?

Tags: xml, wpf, xpath

Preciso que o valor de `<version>` seja retornado para uma variável em uma aplicação WPF. O arquivo XML está no servidor e contém:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<Application>
<Version>1.2.3.5</Version>
<ZipFile>Atu_SGT_1.2.3.5.zip</ZipFile>
</Application>
```

Minha dúvida é como consultar esse XML para verificar o valor de `<version>1.2.3.5</version>`.

Comment: Você está usando alguma linguagem para fazer essa consulta? Possui algum código pronto? Por favor, especifique um pouco mais sua pergunta para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Ok. A aplicação é em WPF. O arquivo xml está no servidor. Minha dúvida é como eu consigo consultar esse xml para verificar o <version>1.2.3.5</version>. Obrigado

Comment: Ok. A aplicação é um WPF em C#. O arquivo xml está no servidor. Minha dúvida é como eu consigo consultar esse xml para verificar o <version>1.2.3.5</version>. Penso em um método que faria isso e ele é chamado no Window_Loaded da aplicação. Obrigado por ajudar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `SelectSingleNode` permite navegar pelo arquivo XML, de acordo com a sua estrutura:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("c:\\seu_arquivo.xml");

XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
string version = node.InnerText;
```

Se você quer trazer o XML de um servidor HTTP, pode tentar carrega-lo e depois ler da mesma forma:

```
var url = "http://seuservidor.com/seu_arquivo.xml";
var xmlVersion = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlVersion);

XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
string version = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado.